# Semantic Markup and ARIA attributes for Table of Contents?

Tags: html, semantic-markup, wai-aria

Are there any recommendations for a simple table of contents for screen readers? Are there any `role` or `aria-`attributes for improving acessibility? Is it enough to put the `<nav>` inside the related article?

```
<nav>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <a href="#lorem">Lorem</a>
        <li>
            <a href="#ipsum">Ipsum</a>
        <li>
            <a href="#dolor">Dolor</a>
    </ol>
</nav>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't really do opinions. If there's no objective criteria by which answers will be judged, it's generally [off-topic according to the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you! I have edited the question.

Answer (score 4):

The table of contents on the [WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices 1.1](https://web.archive.org/web/20191104232308/https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/) website used a `<nav>` element containing an `<h2>` and a nested `<ol>` with links. They haven't added *any* additional ARIA attributes, so I take that as a good sign the inherent semantics of those elements are sufficient for assistive technologies.

Snippet of the start of the table of contents on that page:

```
<nav id="toc">
  <h2 class="introductory" id="table-of-contents">Table of Contents</h2>
  <ol class="toc">
    <li>
      <a... etc.
```